# Google Apps for buisness to Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace

I have created my personal account in Google Apps for business instead of Google Apps. Is it possible for me to change this? I have 13 days of trial time left. today when i get [this](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html) link i get to know that there is a free version still available.

Comment: This type of question is better suited to: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will do it from the next time sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60755